# Listing nameservers in Ubuntu 14.04 without NetworkManager

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, dnsmasq

In Ubunutu 14.04, I want to list the nameservers the machine is using. Normally I would use `nm-tool` to list them, but it appears NetworkManager doesn't run when no user is logged in via the GUI, and I want to do this in an SSH session.

I can't cat `/etc/resolv.conf`, since all it provides is `nameserver: 127.0.1.1`. Am I missing something? Is there another command that I should be using instead?

[edit]

Diffing the running process list gives this:
(with and without gui running)

```
$ ps -eo args --sort=command | grep dbus > gui.txt #or nogui.txt
$ diff gui.txt nogui.txt
4c4
< dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-8cBzgUufwJ
---
> //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
9,10d8
< upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system
< upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-name session
```

So perhaps the issue is that they can't communicate via dbus...?

Comment: Does `nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep DNS` work?

Comment: Reference for other methods: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152593/command-line-to-list-dns-servers

Comment: nmcli gives me the same results as nm-tool; they are both trying to connect to NetworkManager. It appears NetworkManager is running in both cases, but perhaps they just can't communicate (see edits in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine gets its DNS via DHCP you could

```
grep domain-name-servers /var/lib/dhcp/<interface>.leases
```

Comment: Accepting this answer, since it was the most useful, even though it probably won't provide the correct nameserver in non dhcp cases.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the only way to talk to `dnsmasq` is now through D-Bus and `/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf` is empty (bad design IMHO), so either check `var/log/syslog` for the last entry by `dnsmasq` or use the D-Bus interface.

Further info: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/networkmanager-dnsmasq.htm; http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/DBus-interface

Answer (score 0):

Something sounds amiss with your system's setup. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and just rebooted my system and made sure that no one was logged in via the Desktop. I then ssh'ed into the system and can use `nmcli` just fine.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

Here's a list via NetworkManager's cli tool, `nmcli`:

```
$ nmcli dev list | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.101
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.4.4
IP4.DNS[4]:                             208.67.222.222
IP4.DNS[5]:                             208.67.220.220
```

These are all the DNS servers that I've configured my DHCP server to delve out when system's lease their IP addresses from it.

Comment: nmcli works fine for me if the desktop is logged in, but running it via ssh w/ desktop logged out results in: `** (process:16336): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager <snip>`